# Check which columns were modified in an UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

When we update a MySQL record with php, we can check if it has effect using:

```
$mysqli->affected_rows;
```

But how do I check which column has been modified?

Example, in my table have the columns: **id / name / age**

In a record we have the data: **1 / Woton / 18**

If I send an: `UPDATE mytable SET name = 'Woton', age = '20' WHERE id = '1'`

Only the **age** field has changed. How can I determine this?

Comment: theres no builtin functionality to report what columns changed.  we could inspect the current values and compare to the newly assigned values in a trigger, but then we would need some kind of mechanism of communicating that information, from the trigger to the caller. That's not builtin functionality either, so we need to decide if we are going to use user-defined variables, or another table. Since an UPDATE statement can affect multiple rows, we would need to decide how to report results for multiple rows.

Comment: Also `SET id = '1',` with `WHERE id = '1'` will not work in your expected way. As i think `id` is `primary auto-incremented key`

Comment: This trigger, what would it be like? I would configure it in the right db, but how to make it go in the response of the php command? This is the main point

Comment: @AlivetoDie I already tested it and it worked, but **id** will not change, but when I do the query, all fields will go to **SET**, but not all change

Comment: If you're trying to change a row's ID, you're likely doing something wrong.

Comment: Forget the **ID** part, it does not matter, the only thing that matters is you know which column was changed

Comment: `WHERE id = '1'` <-- That's the one that changed. The row with ID of 1. Or am I not understanding something here?

Comment: @Mike Did you read the post? I do not want to know which row has changed, I want to know which row column that changed, in the example I send **2 SET's**, but only one that goes with a different value than was already there

Comment: @WotonSampaio Yeah, I didn't read the question.

Comment: @WotonSampaio You're using PHP. Just select the row before and after the update and compare the values.

Comment: @Mike Would not it have a cleaner way of doing that, no? Because it would be one more query in the process, but it's a good idea anyway

Comment: @WotonSampaio Want MySQL-only, see spencer's comment above, which is way over my head too. One extra query is really not that big of a deal unless you're updating hundreds of rows in separate queries. But here's another idea. Reevaluate whether it's even necessary. Someone updates their info just say "Your info has been updated successfully" and leave it with that. No need to say *what* they updated. They should already know that anyway. Also don't store their "age", store their "birth date".

Comment: @Mike It will only be one line at a time, but it needs to know which column has been modified since a log must be made with the edition of each user of the system so that the admin of the company knows who modified what

Comment: @Mike In that case I think the solution is yours, thank you for opening my mind, I really had not thought about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly get the updated columns from the query result.

It can be get from some php query. Firstly we will have to select the row from database which we are going to update in a array variable. Than run the update query for the same row.

Lastly get the same row from database from select query in the new array variable.

Finally we get two arrays.

We can get the updated column with the array_diff_assoc php function.

See the below code for the same.

```
$sql = "SELECT *  from mytable where id=1 limit 1";
$prev = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $sql));

//Get the column data in the array. Before update.

$sql = "UPDATE mytable SET name = 'Woton', age = '20' WHERE id = '1'";
$conn->query($sql);

// Update data 

$sql = "SELECT *  from mytable where id=1 limit 1";
$updated = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $sql));

// Again run the select command to get updated data.

$UpdatedColumns=array_diff_assoc($updated,$prev);
```

Comment: The third query would not be necessary, I can use the $ _POST itself, but that's right, that's the only solution

Answer (score 1):

In a different note: If QueryLog has been enabled in the DB then you (or your script in PHP or Python or any) can easily see/read which part of the content has been updated and even you can monitor the DB.

The good news is, even you can target which table, which query etc.